# How To Compare Integer to Objective-C enum

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, enums

```
- (void)updateCheckBoxes {
    NSArray *availableFuncUnits = _scanner.availableFunctionalUnitTypes;
    for(int i = 0; i < [availableFuncUnits count]; i++) {

    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the for loop, the elements of the `NSArray *` 'availableFuncUnits' are `(__NSCFNumber *)(int)0` and `(__NSCFNumber *)(long)3`.

The array is supposed to contain elements of the following :

```
enum
{
    ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeFlatbed              = 0,
    ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypePositiveTransparency = 1,
    ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeNegativeTransparency = 2,
    ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeDocumentFeeder       = 3
};
typedef NSUInteger ICScannerFunctionalUnitType;
```

Shouldn't I be able to do the following?

```
if([availableFuncUnits objectAtIndex:i] == ICScannerFunctionalUnitType.ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeDocumentFeeder) {}
```

But it always gives me an error saying 'Expected identifier or '('.

How can I perform this comparison correctly? Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems that I see:
1) The array `availableFuncUnits` contains `NSNumber` objects. You cant directly compare them with primitive types (`NSUInteger`).

So your `if` should be like this:

```
ICScannerFunctionalUnitType type = [availableFuncUnits[i] integerValue]
if(type == ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeDocumentFeeder){}
```

In your snippet you were comparing the pointer, not the object.

2) The error you were seeing is because the proper way to use enums is:

```
i = ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeDocumentFeeder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't store integers in an `NSArray` because array's can only contain objects. To get integers into an array they must be wrapped with `NSNumber`:

```
NSInteger a = 100;
NSInteger b = 200;
NSInteger c = 300;

// Creating NSNumber objects the long way 
NSArray *arrayOne = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:a],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:b],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithInteger:c], nil];
// Creating NSNumber objects the short way
NSArray *arrayTwo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@100, @200, @300, nil];
```

This is relevant you your question because when you extract your `NSNumber` objects from your array, if you want to then compare them to actual integers, you must convert them back to integers (unwrap them).

```
NSLog(@"%d", [arrayOne firstObject] == 100); // COMPILER WARNING!!!
NSLog(@"%d", [[arrayOne firstObject] integerValue] == 100); // True
NSLog(@"%d", [[arrayTwo lastObject] integerValue] == 200);  // False
```

This stage appears to be missing in your example.

Finally to compare your integer values with those from an `enum`, there's no need to reference the `enum` name, just use the individual values that make up the enum:

```
[[arrayTwo lastObject] integerValue] == ICScannerFunctionalUnitTypeFlatbed
```